# I want to crash my mfc application

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

When I execute this...

```
void CcrashDlg::OnBnClickedBtnCrash()
{
    char* ptr = NULL;
    *ptr = 1;
}
```

app just logs "Access Violation", and nothing happened.

How can I crash my MFC application? (visual studio 2010)

Comment: Do you have any exception handlers in place?  I'm not sure, but perhaps MFC does some silly swallowing of exceptions in some contexts (like this button click).

Comment: Try your code using the release build.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart just default generated code with my onbnclickedbtncrash().

Comment: @jussij release does same with debug

Comment: [This](http://blog.paulbetts.org/index.php/2010/07/20/the-case-of-the-disappearing-onload-exception-user-mode-callback-exceptions-in-x64/) might be interesting for you.

Comment: Have you checked your [WER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb513638(v=vs.85).aspx) settings?

Comment: @Michael Walz great referrence! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the answer is hidden in the comments to the question, so I'm going to summarize it here - this is important stuff.

The full details are at this link: [The case of the disappearing OnLoad exception – user-mode callback exceptions in x64](http://blog.paulbetts.org/index.php/2010/07/20/the-case-of-the-disappearing-onload-exception-user-mode-callback-exceptions-in-x64/).

Invalid operations that you would expect to crash the program don't crash in all circumstances. This includes many of the techniques outlined in the other answers.

The problem only occurs when you're using a 64-bit version of Windows and you're within a function that was called by the Windows kernel. In 32-bit versions of Windows, an exception or invalid operation could be caught from the code that called into the kernel, but in 64-bit versions of Windows this is impossible. Windows itself will catch the error at the user/kernel boundary, and *ignore* it! This was judged to be a better outcome than crashing the program every time, since the catch blocks that worked so well in 32-bit don't get a chance to handle the error anymore.

You should still be able to halt the process immediately using [`ExitProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682658%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`TerminateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686714%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but I haven't tried them.

Answer (score 2):

just divide a number by zero,

```
int div = 1;
div--;
int cr = (any number)/div;
```

Answer (score 0):

`Assert( NULL )` will crash your application in debug mode. I don't think you want to crash the release version but if so you can use `Verify`there/both.

Other simple ways to cause crash is just use `sprintf`with wrong formatting specifier for example feed a string when its expecting "%d".

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use to crash my app. I think it is same as yours. In release mode also it crashes.

```
*(int*)0 = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. abort() works on release mode
2. App crashes when compiled win64 platform on 64bit os.